# How to keep the Car Home app from opening automatically on my Droid?

Tags: motorola-droid, cyanogenmod, car-dock

Hey all, this is something that's been bugging me for a while now and I just found this wonderful, glorious place so I thought I'd pick your collective brains.

I'm running CM 6.2.1 on my original Motorola Droid.  I don't want to uninstall the Car Home app, but I don't want it to open automatically when I put my phone in my car dock either.  Aside from ripping apart my dock and pulling out the magnet, is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an app like [Autostarts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts) (requires root) to manage which apps can listen to which events.  You just need to remove Car Home from the docking event.

Comment: @Matthew Read - Very cool, I'm going to hang on to that link but are there any other options?  It seems like overkill to download an app for this.

Comment: @JonnyP Theoretically you could learn just what it is that Autostarts is editing and do the same thing manually, but I'm not sure how myself.  By the way, note that Autostarts requires root.

Comment: @Matthew Read - I think what Autostarts does is prevent the OS from announcing that it's been placed in the car dock (in my case).  I'm pretty sure the Car Home app listens for the "placed in car dock" intent and runs when it that intent runs.  I am rooted (have to be to load a custom ROM), so I suppose I could try to figure out which file runs the intent I'd like to suppress, back it up and then modify it, but that seems mighty dangerous.  Makes me wish Cyanogen would include this as an option in Dock Settings.

Comment: @JonnyP Actually the OS will still announce it, but Autostarts will remove Car Home from the OS's lsit of apps to announce it to (intents aren't broadcast to every app, [they must register with the OS to receive specific ones](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)).  I don't think it should be too dangerous if you're only editing the entry for the docking event, but making a backup is always a good idea.  You could backup with ClockworkMOD / Nandroid if your phone supports it to be worry-free.

Comment: @Matthew Read - I do use ClockworkMod, and that reminds me that I need to make a new backup since I just reflashed last night.  I didn't realize that was how the intents worked; I keep meaning to dig into Android app development and start writing my own stuff but I can never find the time.  :)  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I'm the dev of a Car Home replacement app (Car Dashboard).  Basically the app declares that it acknowledges car mode intents.  So whenever the phone enters car mode, it automatically launches an app that handles that intent.  If you have multiple apps that handle that intent, you get a list of them to choose from (and can set one of them as a default). I guess they never thought about someone wanting for an intent to never be handled.

Comment: @Bryan Denny - I've seen your app, it looks pretty slick.  If I didn't prefer to have my PowerAmp open while on the road I'd definitely be using Car Dashboard.  The speed alerts thing is genius.

Comment: @JonnyP thanks :D at some point in the future I plan on having media controls via headset emulation, but have been doing other feature requests first